# *.cs files set to open with Notepad - how to restore?

Tags: shell-extensions

I accidentally opened a `Aspx.cs` file in Notepad and now all *.cs files have been set to open with Notepad. What should I do to restore this "open with" setting for *.cs files to their original program?

Windows server 2003.

Comment: change open with and check for open with default application change it to microsoft visual studio doesnt it help?

Comment: Do you know what the original program was that opened the *.cs files? Please edit that into your question. And if you don't know, list some programs that you have installed that you think could be the origibal ones.

Answer (score 0):

Right-clicking on a file of the appropriate file type and selecting `Choose Program` from the `Open With...` menu, checking the `Always use this program to open this type of file` box and selecting the desired program (Browse to it if necessary) is the quick and easy fix.

The long and only slightly more difficult fix is to open a Windows Explorer window, select `Folder Options` from the `Tools` menu, then the `File Types` tab. Find the desired file type in the list and press the `Change` button to choose which program you want to open the filetype with. Alternatively you can press `Advanced` to change the context menu options and default program from there, although it shouldn't be necessary.